# Conservation of momentum - the real world usage

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, momentum

I understand that momentum is not conserved between two states if acceleration is not 0. I will denote acceleration as `a` in the below.

There're lots of examples in a textbook where we got 2 objects with masses m1 and m2 where m2 is stationary and m1 is moving and in the end, collides with m2. We can consider 1 dimensional line.

The funny thing is it's stated that m1 moves with a velocity of 20m/s and after the collision(let's say m1 and m2 stick due to collision and overall mass starts to move), it's stated that momentum is conserved.

Since m1 is moving with 20m/s, this statement is not quite right as due to friction, speed can't stay constant. So it must be decreasing. `a` can be constant though if the surface is uniform. If so, the momentum of the whole system changes every millisecond, even though m2 is stationary, m1 is not and it's not having constant speed. So even before the collision, total momentum changes all the time so it's not conserved.

So in order to have it conserved, external forces(from friction, gravitational) e.t.c must be 0, but due to friction it's not.

**Question 1:** In this case, when we write conservation of momentum, I believe we should always calculate "before" momentum at the fraction of millisecond time of instant before the collision, right ? otherwise, calculating it much prior would be too much error prone. What would be the real world use case of this as in the real world, we got actual friction. with my example, we could approximate to figuring out the speed of the overall object after the collision at that instant, quickest time after the collision and this is enough to solve lots of complex problems in life ?

**Question 2:** as I said, "before" momentum should be calculated 0.000001 millisecond before the collision. Then we say it's equal to the "after" momentum which is the 0.000001 millisecond after the collision. As we know, during the collision, internal forces take effect, but I know they cancel each other out. So we're left with the forces that happen during collision that are not internal. Could you explain the effects of these in the real world calculation ? I know we neglect them, but would be lovely to see why they can be neglected(in terms of numbers).

Comment: what does `a != 0` mean?

Comment: updated for better readability

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this.

Comment: @Chemistry this site prefers MathJax, so 'dollar' a \ne 0 'dollar' is preferred. Or to be more clear: $\ddot x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The funny thing is it's stated that m1 moves with a velocity of 20m/s and after the collision(let's say m1 and m2 stick due to collision and overall mass starts to move), it's stated that momentum is conserved.

What is funny about this? An asteroid can easily crash into a planet and be absorbed by the planet, and the momentum is conserved.

> this statement is not quite right as due to friction

If you want to be so anal as to take friction into account everywhere along the way, you can. You might even have to deal with friction suddenly increasing when the 2nd mass starts moving, but in principle, you just have to be careful and compute that contribution.

> In this case, when we write conservation of momentum, I believe we should always calculate "before" momentum at the fraction of millisecond time of instant before the collision, right ? otherwise, calculating it much prior would be too much error prone.

As mentioned right above, you can compute the effect of friction everywhere and everywhen in the trajectory, and thereby know the combined system momentum at every time point, even during any complicated collision.

> we could approximate to figuring out the speed of the overall object after the collision at that instant, quickest time after the collision and this is enough to solve lots of complex problems in life ?

Yes, most situations do not need that absurd levels of precision, and so this works well enough.

> Could you explain the effects of these in the real world calculation ? I know we neglect them, but would be lovely to see why they can be neglected(in terms of numbers).

If there are net external forces acting during the collision, they just modify the system momentum.
$$\Delta\vec p=\int\vec F\mathrm dt\approx0$$
because, by your numbers, 2 nanoseconds multipled by a normal sized force is going to be a completely negligible contribution.

You could have easily answered many of your own questions if you just actually do some computation.